# What is the "best" statistical average?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

Lets say I want to calculate a company's share price using the method of comparable analysis (using ratios)

So I have collected ratios of (such as the EV/EBITDA, EV/revenue, P/E ratios and so on) a set $10 $similar companies and I have taken the median of these ratios.

using these ratios I have found 10 different prices. Say $\$54, \$78, \$34, \$68, \$400, \$146, \$37, \$63, \$48, \$56. $

So, what kind of statistical average should i use now to harmonize these prices? From the calculations there are some inflated prices. So maybe taking the geometric mean, might not be the best?

What should I do? Is there a better way to find the average? Should I find the average at all?

Comment: I do have a comment. Those ratios shouldn't be averaged together. P/E and EV/revenue, for instance, measure different things. Their meanings lose value if they are averaged.

Comment: You need to define with more rigor what you want to know and what you are trying to do. From what you're saying, it sounds like some basic AI / machine learning would be helpful - look at ai tools for multiple features.